# Correct way to use short form of "if" in perl

Tags: perl

I had written series of perl constructs using short form of `if` in perl as below,

```
    ( $psap[0] = sprintf( "%.4f", $psap[0] )
 && ( $psap[0] = "1:" . $psap[0] )
 && push( @all, $psap[0] ) )
            if ( defined( $psap[0] ) );

    ( $psap[1] = sprintf( "%.4f", $psap[1] )
 && ( $psap[1] = "2:" . $psap[1] )
 && push( @all, $psap[1] ) )
            if ( defined( $psap[1] ) );
```

I had faced some issues with this,

1. `sprintf` does not  seems to be working ( Values are not rounded);
2. When I tried to `print $psap[0] and $psap[1]` value I was just getting `1 and 2` respectively and nothing else (`@all` contains the value of `psap[0]` as expected );

I agree that the code is not readable, I wanted some quick way to solve the issue that time. Later I wrote in full form of `if` which was working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logical operators should be avoided if you don't really want to depend on their result, and just want to sequentially execute your code, thus

```
$psap[1] = sprintf("%.4f", $psap[1]), $psap[1] ="2:$psap[1]", push(@all, $psap[1])
  if defined $psap[1];
```

or shorter,

```
defined and $_ = sprintf("%.4f", $_), $_ ="2:$_", push(@all, $_)
  for $psap[1];
```

or shorter,

```
defined and $_ = sprintf("2:%.4f", $_), push(@all, $_)
  for $psap[1];
```

Answer (score 4):

Forget about the `if`... it's a red herring. Focus on this:

```
$psap[1] = sprintf( "%.4f", $psap[1] )
   && ( $psap[1] = "2:" . $psap[1] )
   && push( @all, $psap[1] )
```

That's essentially:

```
$psap[1] = X() && Y() && Z();
```

So you're setting `$psap[1]` to the result of a boolean `&&` operation on three operands.

Either wrap your assignment in parentheses, like this:

```
( $psap[1] = sprintf("%.4f", $psap[1]) )
&& ( $psap[1] = "2:" . $psap[1] )
&& push( @all, $psap[1] )
```

Or use the low-precedence `and` operator:

```
$psap[1] = sprintf("%.4f", $psap[1])
and $psap[1] = "2:" . $psap[1]
and push(@all, $psap[1])
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is a dreadful misuse of the `if` statement modifier, which was never meant to control anything more than the simplest of statements.

I suggest you code it like this, which is far clearer

```
for my $i (0, 1) {
  next unless defined $psap[$i];
  $psap[$i] = sprintf '%d:%.4f', $i + 1, $psap[$i];
  push @all, $psap[$i];
}
```

Comment: This is good advice but the OP was asking why their code wasn't working, so the answer relates to operator precedence. They also stated that they have since written their code using an `if` block anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The assignment to `$psap[0]` [is of lower precedence than the `&&`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Operator-Precedence-and-Associativity), so it is being assigned the value of

```
sprintf( "%.4f", $psap[0] ) && ( $psap[0] = "1:" . $psap[0] ) && push( @all, $psap[0] )
```

Just wrap it in some extra parentheses:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @psap = ( 0.123456789 );
my @all;

( ( $psap[0] = sprintf( "1:%.4f", $psap[0] ) )
    && push( @all, $psap[0] ) 
)
if ( defined( $psap[0] ) );

print $psap[0], "\n";
```

I also took the liberty of putting the "1:" into the `sprintf` rather than building the string in two steps.

As shown in the [operator precedence and associativity table](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Operator-Precedence-and-Associativity), `and` is of a much lower precedence and could be used instead:

```
$psap[0] = sprintf( "1:%.4f", $psap[0] ) and push( @all, $psap[0] ) 
    if ( defined( $psap[0] ) );
```

output:

```
1:0.1235
```